Model conversion from TensorFlow to TensorFlow Lite did not work because not all parameters were quantized to int8
I've tried to convert a TensorFlow model to .tflite, I found the parameters of the .tflite are not all int8, while some parameters also float32. Only the dense parameters are int8, while the conv2d parameters are also float32. Why (The TensorFlow Official website also said: the parameters are quantized as int8.)? I expected all parameters to be quantized, while the activation is not quantized.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04   GPU: RX 3090, TensorFlow: 2.4

The code is as follows:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pathlib
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
test_images = test_images.astype(np.float32) / 255.0


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)),
tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10) 
])
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
              from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(
train_images,
train_labels,
epochs=1,
validation_data=(test_images, test_labels)
)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAUL]

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()

'''
The code for inspect the tensors:
'''

interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path = tflite_model_quant)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
tensor_details = interpreter.get_tensor_details()
for tensor in tensor_details:
    tensor_name = tensor['name']
    tensor_shape = tensor['shape']
    tensor_type = tensor['dtype']
    print(f"Tensor Name: {tensor_name}")
    print(f"Tensor Shape: {tensor_shape}")
    print(f"Number of Parameters: {tensor_params}")
    print(f"Tensor Type:{tensor_type}")
    print(f"Tensor Parameter 
      {interpreter.get_tensor(tensor['index'])}")


The code you've written corresponds to dynamic range quantization in TFLite. As the docs suggest,

This type of quantization, statically quantizes only the weights from floating point to integer at conversion time, which provides 8-bits of precision

and another blogpost from the TFLite team (2) suggests,

Dynamically quantized models are similar to fully-quantized models in that the weights for the Fully Connected and Convolution operators are quantized to 8-bit integers during model conversion. All other tensors are not quantized, they remain as float32 tensors.

It is evident that kernels of Conv2D and weights of the Dense layers are quantized to int8 at conversion time, all other tensors being float32.
Now at inference time, the float32 activations are quantized to int8 to bring optimizations equivalent to a fully int8 quantized model. Another point from (2),

The second difference between full quantization and dynamic range quantization is that the output of the Fully Connected and Convolution operators is in 32-bit floating-point format, as opposed to 8-bit integer for fully-quantized operators.

The possibility of having all parameters quantized to int8 is ruled out with dynamic-range quantization. During model conversion, weights and kernels are quantized to int8 but the activations remain in float32. During inference time, the range of the activation values is observed to quantize them to int8 resulting in better post-quantization quality retention.

Thanks for your answer! I know that the weights are quantized to int8,while other tensors (for example activations) are also float32 in dynamic range quantization.But, in my test, i found that the weights of convolution 2D are also float32,not int8, only the dense layer weights are int8. I don't know why? According to the interpretation,the weights of Conv2D are also need to quantized to int8。The shape of the weights-tensor print as follows: Tensor Name: sequential/conv2d/Conv2D  Tensor Shape: [12  3  3  1]  Tensor Type:<class 'numpy.float32'>  Thank you very much!

Could you share the code that you're using to inspect the tensors and their types?

I have add the code for inspect the sensors in the code. Thank you very much!
